# Iterate all possible variants of a sequence

Tags: algorithm

I have a sequence of n letters: e.g. A B C A D , or A B F A

What I want is to get every possible variant with a comma between the letters.

i.e. for A B F A

A B F A

A,B F A

A B,F A

A B F,A

A,B,F A

A B,F,A

A,B F,A

A,B,F,A

Can anyone recommend a good algorithm for doing this? Language not important.

Comment: If there are `n` letters, there are `n-1` possible comma positions, so `2^(n-1)` variants. Just look at it as binary 1/0 and you see the pattern.

Comment: Use recursion. Branch out two recursions at each step, one with comma at current step, one without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution to use binary array to represent if there is a comma or not.

A B F A contains three positions where comma may be (AB, BF, FA)

That means if you create 3-element array and try every possible combination of 0 and 1 you'll get the desired result. 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111

Simple program in java prints all binary permutation for n bits:

```
 String s = "ABFA";
 int bits = s.length() - 1;
 int lastNumber = (int)Math.pow(2, bits);
 System.out.println(lastNumber);
 for (int i = 0; i < lastNumber; i++) {
     System.out.println(completeZeros(Integer.toString(i, 2), bits));
 }

 static String completeZeros(String s, int bits) {
    String result = s;
    for (int i = 0; i < bits - s.length(); i++) {
        result = "0" + result; 
    }
    return result;
 }
```

To apply binary permutation "010" to string "ABFA" use next function:

```
static String applyBinary(String s, String binary) {
    String result = "" + s.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') result += ", ";
        result += s.charAt(i + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The output is:

```
ABFA
ABF, A
AB, FA
AB, F, A
A, BFA
A, BF, A
A, B, FA
A, B, F, A
```

Answer (score 1):

Use binary system for this task.
1 means comma is present, 0 means comma is not present. Each position in number informs about presence of another comma. For example for AFA:

> 00 : A F A
>
> 01 : A F,A
>
> 10 : A,F A
>
> 11 : A,F,A

Numbers must be taken from range [0 .. (n-1)^2-1]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple JavaScript demonstration.

```
var str = "ABFA";
function algo(str) {
    var result = [];
    var n = str.length;
    var total = Math.pow(n-1, 2) - 1;
    for(var mask = 0; mask < total; mask++) {
        var bits = mask;
        var newstr = "";
        for(var i=0; i<str.length - 1; i++, bits>>>=1) {
            var hasComma = (bits & 1) == 1;
            newstr += str.charAt(i);
            newstr += (hasComma ? "," : " ");
        }
        newstr += str.charAt(str.length - 1);
        result.push(newstr);
    }
    return result;
}
algo(str);
```

- You calculate the total number of combinations "total"
- You count up to that number "mask"
- - You use the binary bits of your counter "bits" to add commas

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this problem.

1.Recursive ( Start = "printAllComb ( s , "" , 0 );" )

```
printAllComb(string s, string const, int i)
 {
    if ( i == s.length() )
           print const
    printAllComb(s,const+string.at(i)+',',i+1);
    printAllComb(s,const+string.at(i),i+1);  
 }
```

2.Dynamic Programming

```
char binaryS[s.length]="0000"; 
//Basically no. of zeros = no. of Alphabets in the string
//define a function AddOne() which adds 1 to the character representation
//AddOne() modifies the character array such that it stays in the bit representation
//Characters because to save space
while ( All the bits are not one )
{
       for ( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++ )
       {
             print s.at(i)
             if ( binaryS.at(i) == '1' )
                print ","                            
       }
       print "\n" 
       AddOne();
}
```